# Connect Rectangles that are adjacent?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, canvas

I want to connect Rectangle-Objects in Array, which are side by side (adjacent). For example:(Structure: "{x: x-Postion, y: y-Postion, x1: width, y1: height}")

```
{x: 0, y: 0, x1: 3, y1: 2}, {x: 0, y: 2, x1: 3, y1: 2}
```

can put together (as I want it) to:

```
{x: 0, y: 0, x1: 3, y1: 4}
```

Till now I couldn't find a solution for my problem, so that I hope you can help me. This a part of my array, where I want to find these side by side - Rectangles and save them in a new Array:

```
[{x:0, y: 0, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 2, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 4, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 6, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 8, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 10, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 12, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 14, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 16, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 18, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 20, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 22, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 24, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 26, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 28, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 30, x1:3, y1:2}//[...]so on
```

Comment: Are x1 and y1 the position of the lower right corner or the size of the rect?

Comment: @adminXVII x1 and y1 are the size of the rect

Comment: have the rectangles the same size and are the postions in a grid?

Comment: @Nina Scholz yes all rectangles have the same size and the postions are in a grid

Comment: are the rectangles in any directions? how should look like the result if a rectangle has a right and bottom adjacent?

Comment: @Nina Scholz If two rectangles are side by side, a new rectangle will be written in a new array with a size of the theses old two rectangles. I have to check if a click by the user is in one of these fields and till now it takes 23ms to check this, so that I hope when I reduce the number of rectangles it will be faster

Comment: What do you mean by "the positions are in a grid" -- is there already a structure that can be leveraged?

Comment: @markE At this moment all rectangles have the same size and some of them a adjacent to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. At the beginning i couldn't recognize that the rectangles were stacked on top of each other. I had to think for all conditions. I believe it recursively searches and merges wherever the rectangles are placed, if their touching edges are same in size.

```js
var rects = [{x:0, y: 0, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 2, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 4, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 6, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 8, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 10, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 12, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 14, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 16, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 18, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 20, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 22, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 24, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 26, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 28, x1:3, y1:2},{x:0, y: 30, x1:3, y1:2}];

function rectsReduce(arr){

  function mergeRects(r,sa,a,i){
   
    function compare(r1,r2){
      return r1.y == r2.y ? r1.x >  r2.x ? r1.x - r2.x == r2.x1
                                         : r2.x - r1.x == r1.x1
                          : r1.x == r2.x ? r1.y > r2.y ? r1.y - r2.y == r2.y1
                                                       : r2.y - r1.y == r1.y1
                                         : false;
    }
   
    var fi = sa.findIndex(e => compare(r,e))+i+1,
    r2 = ~fi ? a.splice(fi,1)[0] : void 0;
 return !!r2 && { x : Math.min(r.x, r2.x),
                  y : Math.min(r.y, r2.y),
                 x1 : r.x == r2.x ? r.x1 : r.x1 + r2.x1,
                 y1 : r.y == r2.y ? r.y1 : r.y1 + r2.y1};
  }
 
  return arr.reduce((p,c,i,a) => { var mergedRect = {};
                                   a.length > 1 && (mergedRect = mergeRects(c,p.slice(i+1),a,i),
                                                    !!mergedRect && (p[i] = mergedRect,
                                                    p = rectsReduce(p)));
                            return p},arr); 
}

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(rectsReduce(rects)) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

An O(n^2) solution would be this:

```
foreach rect as rect1:
  foreach rect as rect2:
    // rect1 above rect2
    if rect1.x == rect2.x && rect1.x1 + rect1.x == rect2.x1 + rect2.x && rect1.y1 + rect1.y == rect2.y:
      outrect = {rect1.x, rect1.x1, rect1.y, rect2.y1+rect1.y1}
      array.remove(rect1,rect2)
      array.add(outrect)
    // rect1 below rect2
    else if rect1.x == rect2.x && rect1.x1 + rect1.x == rect2.x1 + rect2.x && rect1.y == rect2.y1 + rect2.y:
      outrect = {rect1.x, rect1.x1 + rect1.x, rect2.y, rect2.y1+rect1.y1}
      array.remove(rect1,rect2)
      array.add(outrect)
    // rect1 at right of rect2
    else if rect1.y == rect2.y && rect1.y1 + rect1.y == rect2.y1 + rect2.y && rect1.x == rect2.x1 + rect2.x:
      outrect = {rect2.x, rect1.x1 + rect2.x1, rect1.y, rect1.y1}
      array.remove(rect1,rect2)
      array.add(outrect)
    // rect1 at left of rect2
    else if rect1.y == rect2.y && rect1.y1 + rect1.y == rect2.y1 + rect2.y && rect2.x == rect1.x1 + rect1.x:
      outrect = {rect1.x, rect1.x1 + rect2.x1, rect1.y, rect1.y1}
      array.remove(rect1,rect2)
      array.add(outrect)
```

(BTW this is only pseudocode)

Comment: What does "O (n^2)" means?

Comment: It's the order of growth. It means the time taken by this function is relative to the square of the number of rectangle (which may be significant if you have, lets say, a thousand rect)

Comment: When iterating identical sets, your inner loop should only test against the outer loops position+1 (as I was recently reminded by this recent [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745286/html5-canvas-draw-line-distance-between-points/36766325#36766325)).